# ZeroMQ, async blocking sockets

Tags: zeromq

I'm building a distributed system and I would like asynchronous send and recv from both sides with blocking after high water mark.

PUSH/PULL sockets works great, but I wasn't able to bind a PUSH socket. Meaning I can't have a client-PUSH to server-PULL and a server-PUSH to client-PULL, if the client is behind a firewall, since the server can't connect to the client.

In the book, the following is written, but I can't find an example of it.
"REQ to DEALER: you could in theory do this, but it would break if you added a second REQ because DEALER has no way of sending a reply to the original peer. Thus the REQ socket would get confused, and/or return messages meant for another client." http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter3

I only need a one-to-one connection, so this would in theory work for me.

My question is, what is the best practice to obtain asynchronous send and recv with ZeroMQ without dropping packets?

Answer (score 0):

Most ZeroMQ sockets can both bind (listen on a specific port, acting as a server) and connect (acting as a client). It is usually not related to the data flow. See [the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Plugging-Sockets-into-the-Topology) for more info.

Try to bind on your servers PUSH socket and connect from your clients PULL socket.

Comment: Binding on a PULL socket is no problem. But, AFAIK, I tried binding a PUSH and that failed.

Comment: An other alternative is using only a single connection with a [DEALER and ROUTER](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#The-DEALER-to-ROUTER-Combination) socket.

Comment: ZMQ_ROUTER is ZMQ_HWM option action: Drop.